Is there a known way to fix waydroid not rotating with the system, and if so, how?
I'm having some issues with waydroid not following my screen rotation, and after a bit of research I found the best way is to rotate waydroid using sudo waydroid shell wm set-user-rotation lock $rotation when the screen rotates. I can run commands on screen rotation as I'm using a custom script for screen rotation anyways.
This does rotate the waydroid container internally, but the window stays the same, resulting in waydroid windows still not matching the system orientation and being unusable now.
So to summarise:

waydroid does not correctly follow system rotation
I fixed this by rotating the android container internally using a script
except this does not rotate the window, only the content of the window


As you can see the above situation is fine.

When I then rotate the tablet, the waydroid window's content rotates correctly as well because of my script, but the dimentions of the window don't change, making the window 90° rotated in comparison to the rest of the system.
Is there any way known to fix this?
If not, my current plan is to rotate the window 90° in kde plasma, but I haven't found a way to do so yet. So if anyone knows a way to do that, I would like to hear it (but I will make another post about that if no way is known to fix waydroid's issue and no way to do this gets responded here).
